# (Excel - advanced) How to pull unique values from list using range of criteria (array formula)

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Quarterly Changes Summary'!$F$3:$F$1428, MATCH(1, INDEX(('Quarterly Changes Summary'!$A$3:$A$1428=$B$5) * MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$4:$E7, 'Quarterly Changes Summary'!$F$3:$F$1428), 0),), 0),), "")}
```

This formula is in cell **E8**, with **E4:E7** having the same formula. I'm trying to pull unique values from the `Quarterly Changes Summary` worksheet. I need it to pull values with the criteria of **B5** and if they are values distinct from **E4:E7**.

However, `('Quarterly Changes Summary'!$A$3:$A$1428=$B$5)` is giving me an array and `MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$4:$E7,'Quarterly Changes Summary'!$F$3:$F$1428),0)` is giving me a value of **1**, and not an array.

How do I reformat the match formula so that it gives me an array, and thus an array of what fits my criteria of **B5** and values distinct from **E4:E7**.

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution through some revisions. I took out the match(1) index reference and replaced it with MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$4:$E5,'Quarterly Changes Summary'!$F$3:$F$1428)+('Quarterly Changes Summary'!$A$3:$A$1428<>$B$5),0). I was able to select my criteria and add the arrays by adding the ('Quarterly Changes Summary'!$A$3:$A$1428<>$B$5) within the countif.